# Deque changes bytes to ints when it is extended

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, byte, deque

```
from collections import deque

recvBuffer = deque()
x1 = b'\xFF'
recvBuffer.append(x1)
recvBuffer.extend(x1)
x2 = recvBuffer.pop()
x3 = recvBuffer.pop()
print(type(x1))
print(type(x2))
print(type(x3))
```

The above code prints the following on `Python 3.2.3`

```
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'bytes'>
```

Why did the byte change to an int when extend()-ed to a deque?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bytes` are [documented](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#bytes) to be a sequence of integers:

> "bytes" object, which is an immutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256

When you `extend`, you iterate over the sequence.  When you iterate over a `bytes` object, you get integers.  Note that `deque` has nothing to do with this.  You will see the same behavior using `extend` on a normal list, or just using `for byte in x1`.

Comment: Hmm... I guess that makes sense. I am actually adding these bytes into a queue so that I can process them 16 bits at a time. Having to convert them back to bytes after taking them out is rather annoying.